# Will I lose data while removing the corrupted parquet file writen by spark-structured-streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I use spark-structured-streaming as consumer to get the data from kafka, following the guide refer to 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Then save the data to hdfs as parquet file.

Here is my question:
the program is running well but some containers fail rarely(but it did happpend) result in some corrupted parquet files. it will cause the error like [is not a Parquet file (too small length: 4)] or [.parquet is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [56, 52, 53, 51]]
when reading them.
I have to move them to other dirs and make sure the query from hive works well. But I'm not sure whether lead to data lost because of the move.

I know spark-structured-streaming use checkpoint to recovey but as some data have writen as parquet, I'm not sure whether the offset is mark as commited.

Answer (score 1):

I did a very basic exercise of loading a txt file into the file directory that is read by Spark structured streaming. The writestream of structured stream was writing to a parquet file. After loading two files I see that the metadata generated by spark has a mention of both the files. So, if you remove one of them (including the metadata file that is created with the file sink), the read of parquet file fails from HDFS with the exception (File not found).

```
scala> val ParquetDF1 = spark.read.parquet("/user/root/sink2")
19/05/29 09:57:27 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 19, quickstart.cloudera, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:537)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$9.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:610)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$9.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:602)

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): File does not exist: /user/root/sink2/part-00000-454836ef-f7bc-444e-9a6b-e81e640a196d-c000.snappy.parquet
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:2092)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:2062)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1975)
```

The only difference here is- You are using Hive and I am directly building the Parquet dataframe from HDFS.

Comment: maybe I didn't express my question clearly. First I will not move the metadata dir since I only move the files start with 'part-' and end with '.parquet'

Comment: Second, what I truly worry about is about the offsets. Will them exactly continue at the last position recorded when the program restart